# Can't paste Emojis when using Ukelele custom keyboard

Tags: keyboard, windows, keybindings, emoji, ukelele

Using Ukelele I generated a Windows QWERTY layout which I'm used to coz I'm switching between Windows and macOS. Here's the layout for inspection if necessary: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3834p7vofl415h/Czech%20QWERTY%20Win.keylayout?dl=0

I've found out that it's not possible to insert emojis using the system's default Emoji keyboard using fn (globe) key. I can bring up the window and choose emoji but they're never actually pasted. When I switch to any system layout and click on any emoji in the emoji keyboard they're normally pasted. It just for some reason doesn't work when using custom keyboard.

I've also tried remapping keys using the DefaultKeyBinding.dict file but I had a problem with PhpStorm and other apps ignoring this setting.

Is there any way I can use Keyboard layout I'm used to which would support emoji keyboard and will work in all apps?

Big Sur 11.5.1 MacBook Air M1

Comment: Are you trying to paste by using Command V?

Comment: No I've tried pasting them using either double click or enter on selected emoji. The Emoji keyboard window casually closed but never inserted any emoji. This works normally when I have the default keyboard. But once I switch to the one made with Ukelele it stops working (it just closes the window when emoji selected and won't insert anything)